# Math and Array in PHP possible?

Tags: php, arrays, math

I want to do something like....

```
$myvariable_with_a_number_as_content = 10;    
$param = array(
            'amount' => number_format($cart->getTotalPrice(), 2, '.', '') + $myvariable_with_a_number_as_content
        );
```

We say the `$cart->getTotalPrice` is 10 too...

The Summary should be 20 after ...

but its always 10 from the `$cart->getTotalPrice`

Can somebody explain what i am doing wrong please?

Thank You

Comment: when I run your code (with "$cart->getTotalPrice" = 10), print_r($param) gives me "Array ( [amount] => 20 )" - is this what you want?

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that `$param['amount']` is evaluating as 10? I ran the above code (while stubbing out a basic Cart class with a getTotalPrice method that returns 10) and I get `$param['amount']` equalling 20.

Comment: what does `$cart->getTotalPrice()` mean?? Is it a function or a variable. where it is come from?

Comment: The $cart->getTotalPrice() is the complete Price of the order

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do the following instead:

```
$myvariable_with_a_number_as_content = 10;
$param = array(
  'amount' => number_format(($cart->getTotalPrice() + $myvariable_with_a_number_as_content), 2, '.', '')
);
```

Also, is this Magento?

The code could be a bit more readable:

```
define('CUSTOM_VALUE', 10); // same as $myvariable_with_a_number_as_content = 10;

$totalPrice = $cart->getTotalPrice() + CUSTOM_VALUE;

$param = array(
  'amount' => number_format($totalPrice, 2, '.', '')
);
```

Comment: Thank you but both did not work for me....its prestashop....i try to modify a payment modul to add a extra fee....in backoffice all works perfectly variable get saved correctly ..i also can access my variable in Template via Smarty....but the math part did nott work :(

Comment: @CryptoX can you share your code all the way up to where you use $param? It sounds like something else is overriding it.

Comment: @CryptoX is the code you presented used inside smarty template file or application logic file?

Comment: the first code is part of the paymentmodule.php file....the smarty code in my comment is from the views/templates/front/payment_execution.tpl